# Escaping <? on php shorthand enabled server when using require

Tags: php, xml, escaping, shorthand

I'm trying to `require()` my template for rss feed in php. Unfortunately I need to have shorthand tags enabled on server I'm working with.

I have to start my rss with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` and `<? ... ?>` confuses php into thinking he has to parse that line of code.

Is there a way to "escape" that?

here's just the full code of my rss template that I'm trying to include into main php file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <rss version="2.0">

    <channel>
    <title>Kokodakalo!</title>
    <link>http://127.0.0.1/koko/</link>
    <description>Usluga slična twitteru</description>
        <?php $data = $controller->getData(); foreach($data as $post):?>
        <?php require('views/Rss/item.part.v.htm');?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </channel>

    </rss>
</xml>
```

Comment: Also as ``<?xml...`` isn't a document tag per se, you shouldn't need ``</xml>``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For XML files, the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` is optional (and actually the default like you write it), so you can just remove it and therefore could fix the problem for this case.

Comment: this solution may work in this case, but you won't always be so lucky -- you may find a case where you need to provide different encoding, etc.  This clash was pretty much the #1 reason why PHP decided to deprecate short tags. Important to know that it is deprecated - this means a future version of PHP could remove support for short tags altogether. Best answer is to fix your code NOW so it doesn't use them, to avoid problems in the future.

Comment: @Spudley: Yes the `<?`-short-tag is incompatible with XML, `<?=` and `<?php` are compatible processing instructions.

Comment: @hakre - true. Although `<?=` was also deprecated in PHP5.3 along with other short tags, it has been re-instated in 5.4.

Comment: It was deperecated, but it's now a first-grade language feature you can't disable any longer.

Answer (score 4):

You could `<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'; ?>`

Comment: Thought of that, but I have to keep things as clean as possible for this assignment.

Comment: Then go with hakre's answer, so long as your lecturers also know it's optional.