# Why can't I embed php in the xml file?

Tags: php, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Escaping <? on php shorthand enabled server when using require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457409/escaping-on-php-shorthand-enabled-server-when-using-require)

What I want is that when I make a Ajax get request to `domain/xml.php`. It return a XML file, so I can use httpRequest.responseXML to parse the XML file.

what I did is:

```
<?php
    $name = 'Just a tester';
?>

<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<name><?php echo $name ?></name>
```

But the parser gives me an error of the line `<?xml version='1.0' ?>`, I thought it might be syntax conflict with the php delimiter `<?php`.

How can I request a url and get xml generated by php?

Comment: Do you have php short tags enabled? I could imagine that this is why it gives you an error.

Comment: @Charles sorry I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to embed PHP variables into XML instead of generating the XML with PHP?

Example (xml.php):

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');

//Your Data
$persons = array(array('name'=>'bob','age'=>20,'sex'=>'M'),
                 array('name'=>'steve','age'=>26,'sex'=>'M'),
                 array('name'=>'jen','age'=>33,'sex'=>'F'),
                 );


$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><persons/>');

foreach ($persons as $person) {
    $node = $xml->addChild('person');
    foreach($person as $key=>$value){
        $node->addChild($key, $value);
    }
}
//DOMDocument to format code output
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());

echo $dom->saveXML();

/* OUTPUT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persons>
  <person>
    <name>bob</name>
    <age>20</age>
    <sex>M</sex>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>steve</name>
    <age>26</age>
    <sex>M</sex>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>jen</name>
    <age>33</age>
    <sex>F</sex>
  </person>
</persons>
*/
?>
```

Comment: It works! and +1 for the header section. without it, it always be treated as html

Answer (score 3):

You have shorttags enabled. This is the default, and as of PHP 5.4,  tags are supported everywhere, regardless of shorttags settings.

The problem is that `<?xml version='1.0' ?>` starts and ends with `<? ?>`, just like PHP with shorttags.

To get round this use:

```
echo "<?xml version='1.0' ?>";
```

on that line.

Comment: this doesn't work, the response is`<--xml version='1.0' -->`, maybe I should use simpleXML to generate the xml file

Comment: now it works, with header to define the doctype

Comment: Lawrence is right, there are benefits to using simpleXML, but it can be more complex if you only need very simple XML files.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
$name = 'Just a tester';
echo "<?xml version='1.0' ?>";
?>

<name><?php echo $name; ?></name>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, with header it works as well

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
echo "<?xml...?>";
```

to

```
echo '<'."?...?".'>';
```

Or use Lawerence solution

Comment: +1 for point out this solution

Answer (score 0):

You should set up your webserver to process not only PHP but XML files also through the PHP preprocessor.

Answer (score -2):

You have short tags enabled. These should be disabled in your php.ini, search for "short_open_tag" and "asp_tag".

If you have an earlier version than PHP 5.3.0 this will probably work (if you only want this for the current document):

```
<?php ini_set('short_open_tag', 0); ?>
```

Comment: Shorttags shouldn't be disabled.

Comment: Might be a personal preference, but short-tags are just lazy and creates conflicts - as proven by this question.

Comment: XML Prologs are the only place this comes up. I wouldn't recommend disabling them though, as if any 3rd party code uses them then it can be hard to debug.

Comment: @Daniel sorry it doesn't work